# issues with K8s compiled docker images

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

after cloning repo (tag v1.14.0)to local machine; i have modified `cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go` file; i hvae added one line of new code which is custome log entry
upon K8s code compilation i found docker images tar ball in `_output/release-images/amd64/`  and i used `docker load -i _output/release-images/amd64/kube-apiserver.tar`

it adds a newly built apiserver docker image but, rather than overwriting to tag  it creates a new tag `v1.14.0-dirty`

[image]

now my question is **how and why K8s is adding `dirty` suffix to image tag?**
Now when i do kubeam init it will still deploy original image with `v1.14.0` tag and will not deploy newly built image which has `v1.14.0-dirty` tag

**how do i launch K8s with newly built docker images?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add another command:

```
docker tag k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.14.0-dirty k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.14.0
```

That should create the correct tag for the image.

The `dirty` tag could be applied during the tar build stage as the builder detects that the git repository state is *dirty*.

Comment: Yes this is how made progress initially;  thanks for heads up.

Comment: For now i dont see other way out ; but there has to be a proper way

Answer (score 1):

Kubeadm creates manifests for api server, controller, scheduler services under /etc/kubernetes /manifests.

Update the api server image name in the above path and then delete api server pods.

Comment: these yaml keep getting overwritten after `kubeadm init`; making changes here to use custom image tag does not work.

Comment: kubeadm init is one time activity. if you run multiple times then cluster is re-iniitialized every time